# iOS Deep Linking from Twitter/Instagram

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, deep-linking, associated-domains

We implemented deep linking for user generated content on our app, and from the browser or notes app works perfectly well. I have my associated domains set up for our website.

How our deep linking works is like this: You click a link to a post on the website/app -> you're directed to the app and it opens that post (if the app is downloaded). If the app is NOT downloaded it loads the post on the website.

The issue is that if I post that link to twitter, it will only open in their web view, even when the app is downloaded. Is there a way to by pass this so that people can directly open my app from twitter with a post link?